# How to plot spheres on top of scattered stars in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to make a scattered stars and plot multiple spheres on top of it? I tried doing this:

```
x = rand(100,1); y = rand(100,1); z = rand(100,1);
scatter(x,y,z,'c*')
```

After this I tried plotting sphere but the sphere pushes the stars to the side. How do I fix this?

```
vec = [1;1;1]; rads = 1;
[x y z] = sphere;
x = rads*x+vec(1); y = rads*y+vec(2);
z = rads*z+vec(3);

surf(x, y, z, 'Edgecolor', 'none')

colormap colorcube
```

[image]

As you can see it pushed the stars to the side

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pushing the scatter plot to the side because the range of the 'stars' is `[0 1]` because the command `rand(...)` generates values between 0 and 1. On the other hand, the sphere goes from 0 to 2 in all 3 directions.

To fix the problem, you can simply multiply the data used to generate the scatter plot by 2, so they will be in the range `[0 2]`.

Doing so results in the following:

[image]

And the code. Note that I used `scatter3` instead of `scatter`.

```
clear
clc
close all

xs = 2*rand(100,1); ys = 2*rand(100,1); zs = 2*rand(100,1);
hScatter = scatter3(xs,ys,zs,'c*')

hold on

vec = [1;1;1]; rads = 1;
[x y z] = sphere;
x = rads*x+vec(1); y = rads*y+vec(2);
z = rads*z+vec(3);

surf(x, y, z, 'Edgecolor', 'none')

colormap colorcube

rotate3d on
```